# httpContext.Current.Session is null (Inside WebService) Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

I have an web service.And i am using some session variables in that service.

### Code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string UploadFiles_Local(Dictionary<int, string> accFile)
{
    string FilePath = "";
    Dictionary<int, string> dicStatus = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Dictionary<int, string> dicUpload = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("UplodedFiles") + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    foreach (var f_l in accFile)
    {
        FilePath = f_l.Value;
        string fName = FilePath.Substring(FilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, FilePath.Length - FilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

        //File reading
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        //Directory Existens checking
        if (!Directory.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString()))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            //Upload files
            long FileSize = new FileInfo(FilePath).Length; // File size of file being uploaded.
            string uploadFileName = new FileInfo(FilePath).Name; // File name

            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[FileSize];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();
            fs = null;

            fs = File.Open(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString() + "\\" + fName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            bw.Write(buffer);
            bw.Close();

            dicStatus.Add(f_l.Key, "File " + fName + ". Successfuly uploded to:" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString() + "\\" + fName);
            dicUpload.Add(f_l.Key, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString() + "\\" + fName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
            dicStatus.Add(f_l.Key, "File " + fName + ". Error in uploding to:" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString() + "\\" + fName + "\r\nError :" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    if (dicUpload.Count > 0)
    {
        //Making rar of uploded files
        ClsClass.RarFilesT(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString() + ".rar", dicUpload);
        FilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uLocal"].ToString() + ".rar";
    }
    else
    {
        FilePath = "Error";
    }
    return FilePath;
}
```

I have already enabled session in that web service but stile i get error message :-

### Error message:-

```
 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current' is null
```

And one more ting i need to call this service from globle.ashx file.

Comment: please add more details..

Comment: Please check add code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service

But let me tell you that a Web Service should not stored any session states, that is just wrong.

Comment: This is working when we call that service from any aspx form.
But i need to call that service from Global.asax file.
When we call that service from Global.asax file it troughs error message

Comment: I would have to see the code to give any more inputs.